# How to create listener to custom variable inside document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This code updating when any change inside document but I want when change custom variable not any variable.

For example I want call this funcation when change `Score` variable.

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore.document('Test/uhfL5NE199eYTGyfSH1srtrtee').onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const washingtonRef = admin.firestore().collection('Test').doc('uhfL5NE199eYTGyfSH1srtrtee');
  return washingtonRef.update({Counts:admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. With Cloud Function and Firestore an `.onUpdate(`) is triggered when a document already exists and has **any value** changed (See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).

What you can do is to use the two snapshots that represent the data state **before** and **after** the triggering event and that are present in the `change` object, as follows:

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore.document('Test/uhfL5NE199eYTGyfSH1srtrtee').onUpdate((change, context) => {

  const newValue = change.after.data();
  const previousValue = change.before.data();

  //Check if the Score field has changed
  if (newValue.Score  !== previousValue.Score) {

    //Score field has changed! -> Do whatever you want

  } else {
     //End the Cloud Function
     return false;
  }


});
```

Comment: Can I know what's variable name is changed ?

Comment: Okay I apprecaite you help , Thank you.